# Converting a UNIX timestamp into a Date object in Elm

Tags: date, elm

As the title reads, how can I convert a UNIX timestamp, e.g. 1458297862, into a Date object in Elm?

`Date.fromString` does not seem to accept it, and `Date.fromTime` gives the wrong answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Date.fromTime`, but you have to [multiply that value by `1000`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676195/why-do-i-need-to-multiply-unix-timestamps-by-1000-in-javascript).

This gives you the date you'd expect:

```elm
Date.fromTime 1458297862000
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across this answer and it didn't quite work in 0.18.

I found that Date.fromTime wouldn't accept arbitrary integers.  The reason is that it's expecting floats, so you'd really want:

```
Date.fromTime (toFloat 1458297862000)
```