# Elm: Json decoder timestamp to Date

Tags: elm

I'm trying to convert a timestamp (ex: "1493287973015") from a JSON to a Date type.

So far I created this custom decoder:

```
stringToDate : Decoder String -> Decoder Date
stringToDate decoder =
  customDecoder decoder Date.fromTime
```

But it doesn't work because it has return a Result, not a Date:

```
Function `customDecoder` is expecting the 2nd argument to be:

    Time.Time -> Result String a

But it is:

    Time.Time -> Date.Date
```

Is there a way to do a conversion?

Comment: ...and if it is a UNIX timestamp, remember to [multiple that value by 1000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676195/why-do-i-need-to-multiply-unix-timestamps-by-1000-in-javascript)...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming your JSON is actually placing the numeric value inside quotes (meaning you are parsing the JSON value `"1493287973015"` and not `1493287973015`), your decoder could look like this:

```elm
import Json.Decode exposing (..)
import Date
import String

stringToDate : Decoder Date.Date
stringToDate =
  string
    |> andThen (\val ->
        case String.toFloat val of
          Err err -> fail err
          Ok ms -> succeed <| Date.fromTime ms)
```

Notice that `stringToDate` doesn't get passed any parameters, as opposed to your example in which you were attempting to pass a `Decoder String` as a parameter. That's not quite how decoders work.

Instead, this can be done by building upon more primitive decoders, in this case, we start with the decoder [`string` from `Json.Decode`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Json-Decode#string).

The `andThen` portion then takes the string value given by the decoder, and tries to parse it to a float. If it is a valid `Float`, it is fed into `Date.fromTime`, otherwise, it's a failure.

The [`fail`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Json-Decode#fail) and [`succeed`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Json-Decode#succeed) functions wrap up the normal values you're dealing with into `Decoder Date.Date` contexts so they can be returned.

Comment: Thanks! I got it working. Decoding JSON with Elm is not exactly easy.

Comment: I wouldn't go far as to say it isn't _easy_. It's just unfamiliar if you've come from an imperative background. This kind of parsing is fairly common in functional languages; it's known as Parser Combinators.

Answer (score 6):

Two things, a JSON may actually have the milliseconds as an integer, not a string and things have changed since v 0.19 of Elm.

Given that your JSON looks something like.

```
{
    ...
    "someTime": 1552483995395,
    ...
}
```

Then this would decode to a Time.Posix:

```
import Json.Decode as Decode

decodeTime : Decode.Decoder Time.Posix
decodeTime =
    Decode.int
        |> Decode.andThen
            (\ms ->
                Decode.succeed <| Time.millisToPosix ms
            )
```

Comment: ...and if it is a UNIX timestamp, remember to [multiple that value by 1000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676195/why-do-i-need-to-multiply-unix-timestamps-by-1000-in-javascript)...