# Decoding epoch millis to "DateTime" in Elm 0.19?

Tags: datetime, elm

Let's say I have an epoch millis value such as `1538637258426`, how do I convert that into a something like a `DateTime` representation in Elm 0.19?

I'm not even sure which model I should use to represent a "date time" in Elm 0.19. I cannot find the Date module in core that is referred to from a lot of places on the web (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146233/elm-json-decoder-timestamp-to-date) stackoverflow question). Also I cannot seem to install the `elm-community/elm-time` package since it's not upgraded to support 0.19.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The official date/time library in 0.19 is [`elm/time`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/time/latest/), which has replaced the old `Date` module in core. The type you'll want to use is [`Time.Posix`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/time/latest/Time#Posix), which you can obtain from a milliseconds value using [`Time.millisToPosix`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/time/latest/Time#millisToPosix).