# Data being plotted is multiplied by 1000 on its own in Highcharts using Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, deep-copy

The data I am trying to plot is of the form :

```js
[
    [24894174208.0, 1604842800],
    [24903880704.0, 1604843100]
]
```

```
where x = data points; y = UNIX_EPOC_Time
```

while plotting I am interchanging x,y; so as to plot `UNIX_EPOC_Time` on `X-axis` & data points on `Y-axis`

I have to multiply `UNIX_EPOC_Time` by `1000` as: Javascript uses milliseconds internally, while normal `UNIX` timestamps are usually in seconds. ( [Why do I need to multiply unix timestamps by 1000 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676195/why-do-i-need-to-multiply-unix-timestamps-by-1000-in-javascript) )

Also I am trying to find anomalies in the dataPoints which is being plotted with a dot (yellow/orange/red).

However, in the function

```
js[isIn(anomoly, point){...}]
```

where I find anomalies in dataPoints, I see the datapoints take the form as:

```js
[1604923500000, 22179459072000]
```

instead of:

```js
[1604923500, 22179459072.0]
```

due to which I have to divide the data point (here: `22179459072000`) by `1000` to bring it to it's original form `22179459072.0` in order to plot it on the graph.

I am not sure why this is happening though.

I have reproduced the issue in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/highchart-highstock-fohpsm?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: It is happening because the `getDummyData()` method is mutating your initial data at some point. Just check how the `this.data.Result[0].anomalies` looks like at the end of the `getDummyData()`, `[24508948480000, 1604872800]` the first element is mutated.

Comment: @MateuszKornecki yes its getting mutated at that place itself, I checked by adding : console.log(this.data.Result[0].anomalies.critical[0]);  to ngOnInit(). Is there a way to prevent it ? https://stackblitz.com/edit/highchart-highstock-bzujdf?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging, I finally found the source of the problem.

It is happening because of the way you are cloning your data.

```js
let clone_element = { ...element };
```

The spread operator is not creating a deep copy of the element, it's just the shallow one meaning that some parts of the `clone_element` will still have a reference to the source of data causing mutation.

To fix that you could use for example the lodash's `cloneDeep()`. This function will produce a real deep copy, so there is no way you will mutate your initial data.

```js
const clone_element = cloneDeep(element);
```

**Live demo:**

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/highchart-highstock-pddlto?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

**Additional references:**

- [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)
- https://dassur.ma/things/deep-copy/
- https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep

Comment: Thanks for sharing the cloneDeep() , but data is still getting mutated , I have added 2 console lines in the code : ``` console.log('ORIGINAL = ', this.data.Result[0].anomalies['critical'][0]); ```   and  ```console.log('NEW = ', clone_element["anomalies"]["critical"][0]) ```   where extra 0s are still being added : https://stackblitz.com/edit/highchart-highstock-7v4x3v?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: The initial data (`this.data`) is not mutated. 
```javascript
ORIGINAL, after getDummyData()=[24894174208, 1604842800]
NEW =[24894174208000, 1604842800]
ORIGINAL, before getDummyData() = [24894174208, 1604842800]
```https://stackblitz.com/edit/highchart-highstock-eawv12?file=src/app/app.component.ts.
Additional zeros are added to the `clone_element` because you did it intentionally, if you don't want them there just delete the lines that are adding them. So to sum up - there is a difference between `original` and `new` and will be in your console.log but the initial data is not mutated.